# A guide to the 10k tools

Tags: support, 10k-tools

I recently got access to the 10k moderation tools. But I don't really understand them. What should I do with the flags page? add flags to those flags I agree with?

Could we have a CW answer to this that is a short guide to the 10k tools? Or is there already one? (I couldn't find one after a quick search...)

Comment: You should be able to vote for closing questions. Otherwise it would surprise me. Moderators can still vote for close, but this automatically closes the question. What error do you get?

Comment: @Martin Oh I can. I thought the link had just disappeared. But it's there. I don't know what went wrong there... But the rest of my question is still valid I think...

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that point. This is a very good question. The moderation tools are sometimes quite confusing. Note that the disagree-with-flags feature is very new.

Comment: Some time ago I asked a similar question at meta.stackoverflow: [Which actions using the 10k-moderator-tools do really help the diamond moderators?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96473/156902). I got two answers from Stack Overflow moderators, which I think mainly apply here, too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A short overview of the current 10k tools pages.

- **stats**:
  This page is mainly an overview of questions that might be worth closer inspections. I guess it is pretty self-explanatory. I usually have a look at the recently migrated questions (because they often need attention), the new tags (because they are often an indication of mis-tagging) and negatively voted questions. You can click on the triangles to expand the lists (this of course also applies to the other pages).
- **migrated**: A list of all migrated questions. For the current amount of migrated questions per day the list on the stats page is long enough. So this page is pretty useless most of the time.
- **close**: Lists recent close/open votes and recently closed/reopened questions. I usually go through this list once a day and add my vote to any questions that I think should be closed (or sometimes a comment that I disagree with the votes). This makes it more likely that a question that should be closed gets five votes.
- **delete**: Same as the close list, but for deleting questions (once a question has been closed for two days, you can vote to delete them). The page also lists answers deleted by mods, but does not list questions an answers deleted by their owners. I usually find this page pretty useless (though it is probably more valuable on bigger sites).
- **flags**: Lists posts that have been flagged by users or by the system. You can go through the list and add your own flags. On this page (and only here) you can also flag a flag as invalid. Adding additional flags can help the moderators to prioritize they actions (though this is way more important on bigger sites than on TeX.sx). Also SPAM posts are deleted automatically when they accumulate enough flags. The page doesn't list flags by moderators and non-specific flags (the 'other' flag) and once you took some action on a flag, the system won't show you that flag anymore.

  For posts automatically flagged by the system it might be possible to improve the post or at least add a comment to inform the user of best practices on SE sites.
- **links**: This once had a lot more pages linked than it has now. There is a link to a list of past suggested edits, which can be interesting if you want to look something up (e.g. if you suspect some strange edit pattern), but isn't that useful otherwise. There is also an (experimental?) page that show some stats about [feedback by anonymous users and users that aren't yet allowed to vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98630/anonymous-user-feedback-now-in-testing). Doesn't seem to be particularly useful at the moment.

In addition to the above pages, the 10k tools menu bar also links to `/review`, but I think that page is accessible to all users. 10k users also get notified on the top bar of any pending suggested edits.

Answer (score 3):

I only had access to the tools for the last month of the beta, back in the days when one didn't have to work so hard for such privileges.

The only meta.SO thread tagged both [faq] & [10k-tools] is [What are the moderation tools available to high-reputation users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4565/what-are-the-moderation-tools-available-to-high-reputation-users), which seems to cover the bases.